# Algorithms/services to know an "iPhone case" is not an "iPhone", in the context of complex item descriptions?

Tags: text-mining, text, search

We are trying to implement a highly accurate search, based on user-entered search terms, into a large product database.

For example, if the user searches for "iPhone", then one of these is potentially what they want, but the other is not:

`Apple iphone 5s Grey 32GB 4G smartphone Unlocked new 1 yr wty`

`Apple iphone 5s case new 1 yr wty`

It would be a failure if the search returned the latter before, or instead of, the former.

The single word "case" in the second product title, made it 'not an iPhone', but all the other words were not relevant.

Assume we have no existing data of which is a 'correct' result or not.

Which seems to mean we have a language-related problem - Which words in a product title/description are important, and which are not? - Relative to a user's search terms.

Not knowing much about data science, I am looking for some steerage.

This looks like a common search problem.

Could anyone point me to an algorithm, or better yet, an existing service of some kind, that could help us with achieving an accurate search result in this scenario?

Sorry, if this isn't sufficiently specific, but not not knowing what I don't know, I am not sure I know how to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing is called "[query rewriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_Rewriting)", taking a user's string literal and processing it to find the best items in the search index.

You can always start with rule-based logic to parse queries, either hard-coded or regular expressions.

Then move to statistical learning methods to improve query rewriting. A user's query should be tokenized based on the [collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation), frequently occurring n-grams. Tokenizing on collocations would group together meaningful words.

There is also session-based context. Create an overall session state (e.g., "phones" or "fruit"). Each token would contribute changes in session, some tokens would contribute a little and others would contribute a lot. For example, the presence of "case" would automatically void the "phone" state. The session state would then change term weightings. Session state works well because users often make several queries in a role, called query refinement.

Comment: Very helpful thanks Brian, you've given me somewhere to start, which is infinitely more helpful than the non-commenting down-voters...